# Open password-protected ods file with python-xlswriter or bash

Tags: python, bash, ubuntu, spreadsheet, libreoffice

I need a code to open spreadsheet via python3 (preferred) or bash that I give them password and they read them.

I try by python-module "xlswriter"

I protect xlsx with this method:

---

```
import xlsxwriter
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('for-test-password.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
content = (
    ['Gas', 10],
    ['Gasoline',   20],
    ['Potro',  30],
    ['Other',40],
)

row = 0
col = 0
for item, cost in (content):
    worksheet.write(row, col,     item)
    worksheet.write(row, col + 1, cost)
    row += 1
worksheet.protect('Passwd')
```

or try with this code in bash-script

```
LibreOffice -p password -f xlsx for-test-password.xlsx
```

But this does not return data in spreadsheet.

Comment: Post your code, if you have tried something.

Comment: I edit question and insert code to it

Comment: The question's title is totally different than the question's body & example. One is about reading / opening / decrypt --- while the other is about writing / saving / encrypt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I protect xlsx with this method:
>
> ```
> worksheet.protect('Passwd')
> ```

This is not password protecting the workbook. It is protecting the worksheet. There is no support in XlsxWriter for password protecting a workbook/xlsx file.

From the [XlsxWriter docs on protect()](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#worksheet-protect):

> **Note**
>
> Worksheet level passwords in Excel offer very weak protection. They do not encrypt your data and are very easy to deactivate. Full workbook encryption is not supported by XlsxWriter since it requires a completely different file format and would take several man months to implement.

Comment: The issue is that (AFAIK) it would take a large amount of work in XlsxWriter to support a different files format just to enable encryption.

Answer (score 0):

`You missed the workbook.close()`

Find the code.

```
import xlsxwriter
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('for-test-password.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
content = (['Gas', 10],['Gasoline', 20],['Potro', 30],['Other',40],)
row = 0
col = 0
for item, cost in (content):
    worksheet.write(row, col, item)
    worksheet.write(row, col + 1, cost)
    row += 1
    worksheet.protect('Passwd')
workbook.close()
```

Note: Above code is working fine in python2.7

To open a password protected in terminal/bash you need a module which can be found [here](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/141626/open-password-protected-file-via-command-line/)

Worksheet protected and their attributes can be found [here](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#worksheet-protect)

Comment: No this is not working , because i need to open worksheet that protected by this program i.e i need to open first document by "password" then edit it and finally set password with "Passwd"

Comment: Your question is unclear. The code you wrote is to open a new file and add content and set the password to the sheet. That's all. If you need to open the existing file which has a password you have to rewrite a code to open file and change the password ( module 'xlrd' ).

Comment: yes this is my idea, you say me must be use of "xlrd" to open the protected xlsx file ? there is no way to open with "xlsxwriter"?