# Is there a programmatic way to read / open / decrypt Libreoffice ODS files (preferably python / bash)

Tags: passwords, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I need to read, programmatically, data from a password-protected ODS (A Libreoffice Spreadsheet file). I know the password.

So far I tried:

1. libreoffice command line.  There isn't any libreoffice switch for passwords.
2. pyexcel_ods3 (doesn't deal with passwords at all)
3. openpyxl (doesn't open ODS)
4. pandas_ods_reader (no password handling AFAIK)
5. via libreoffice macro: I'm aware of this method, buy it doesn't suit my needs.

none of the tools I found even mention "password" in their code/docs.

Are there other ways to read / convert / open password-protected ODS files?

**NOTES:**

n.b. I know the password, I own the file, and I can open the file via GUI by entering the password manually.

[This questions is NOT related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58705829/open-password-protected-ods-file-with-python-xlswriter-or-bash) to # 58705829 . That Q is confused, and probably asking about WRITING, not READING.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`unoconv`](https://github.com/unoconv/unoconv) to decrypt the files *(though not the one from the Ubuntu repo, which is prior to [this commit](https://github.com/unoconv/unoconv/pull/358/commits/7b9ea038671ca5e51daeb426a251bf586686a467), and not from the FreeBSD packages, which also doesn't work out of the box)*.

Usage:

`unoconv --password=$PASSWORD -d spreadsheet -f ods -o decrypted encrypted.ods`

Which will create a `decrypted.ods` file.

Also works with encrypted xls/xlsx files.

Confirmed on an Ubuntu variant and also FreeBSD, using both the current github release and also the current pip package (unoconv-0.9.0).